# React-redux persist, rehydrate only some nodes in the redux-state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, redux-persist

How do I rehydrate only one node of the redux state? I mean, I want everything else to be reset when I refresh the page.

Answer (score 1):

The Blacklist & Whitelist will help you. The sample code is as below. You can find it from redux-persist's documentation. Hope it helps

```js
// BLACKLIST
const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage: storage,
  blacklist: ['navigation'] // navigation will not be persisted
};

// WHITELIST
const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage: storage,
  whitelist: ['navigation'] // only navigation will be persisted
};
```